# Python+C is (slightly) faster than pure C

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I've been implementing the same code (the number of ways to deal a hand in Blackjack without busting) in a variety of languages and implementations. One oddity I've noticed is that the implementation of Python calling the partitions function in C is actually slightly faster than the entire program written in C. The same appears to be true for other languages (Ada vs Python calling Ada, Nim vs Python calling Nim). This seems counterintuitive to me - any idea how this is possible?

The code is all in my GitHub repo here:

https://github.com/octonion/puzzles/tree/master/blackjack

Here's the C code, compiled using 'gcc -O3 outcomes.c'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int partitions(int cards[10], int subtotal)
{
    //writeln(cards,subtotal);
    int m = 0;
    int total;
    // Hit
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (cards[i] > 0)
        {
            total = subtotal + i + 1;
            if (total < 21)
            {
                // Stand
                m += 1;
                // Hit again
                cards[i] -= 1;
                m += partitions(cards, total);
                cards[i] += 1;
            }
            else if (total == 21)
            {
                // Stand; hit again is an automatic bust
                m += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}

int main(void)
{
    int deck[] =
    { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 16 };
    int d = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // Dealer showing
        deck[i] -= 1;
        int p = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            deck[j] -= 1;
            int n = partitions(deck, j + 1);
            deck[j] += 1;
            p += n;
        }

        printf("Dealer showing %i partitions = %i\n", i, p);
        d += p;
        deck[i] += 1;
    }
    printf("Total partitions = %i\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the C function, compiled using 'gcc -O3 -fPIC -shared -o libpartitions.so partitions.c'.

```
int partitions(int cards[10], int subtotal)
{
    int m = 0;
    int total;
    // Hit
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (cards[i] > 0)
        {
            total = subtotal + i + 1;
            if (total < 21)
            {
                cards[i] -= 1;
                // Stand
                m += 1;
                // Hit again
                m += partitions(cards, total);
                cards[i] += 1;
            }
            else if (total == 21)
            {
                // Stand; hit again is an automatic bust
                m += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

And here's the Python wrapper for the C function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ctypes import *
import os

test_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath("libpartitions.so"))
test_lib.partitions.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int), c_int]
test_lib.partitions.restype = c_int

deck = ([4]*9)
deck.append(16)

d = 0

for i in xrange(10):
    # Dealer showing
    deck[i] -= 1
    p = 0
    for j in xrange(10):
        deck[j] -= 1
        nums_arr = (c_int*len(deck))(*deck)
        n = test_lib.partitions(nums_arr, c_int(j+1))
        deck[j] += 1
        p += n
    print('Dealer showing ', i,' partitions =',p)
    d += p
    deck[i] += 1

print('Total partitions =',d)
```

Comment: Is it still faster if you remove all print functions?

Comment: How exactly are you timing this?

Comment: Also, have you compared the actual equivalent C code, which does a `dlopen` and `dlsym` and calls the function pointer, rather than calling normally? I can't imagine why it would be faster that way, but then I can't imagine why the Python would be faster either, and this would at least narrow down where our imaginations are failing. :)

Comment: Thanks! As I've mentioned, C calling C using `dlopen` and `dlsym` was much faster than standalone C. Here is [my code](https://github.com/octonion/puzzles/tree/master/blackjack/c-c).

Comment: Well, every optimizer has corner cases where it occasionally pessimizes instead, and I guess you found one for gcc 5. I wonder if compiling with a lower -O setting would actually make the static version faster? For a less silly solution, what if you PGO the static version and run it a few times?

Comment: I tried Intel's icc compiler. The C version is very slightly faster than the C calling C version, compiling with either -O3 or using PGO. That was the behavior I was originally expecting from gcc. Also worth a note - the gcc executables are faster than the icc executables both with C and with C calling C.

Comment: I just attempted using PGO with gcc, but the resulting code was still slower than C calling C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason here is how GCC compiles function `partitions` in 2 cases. You can compare asm code in `outcomes` binary executable and `libpartitions.so` by using `objdump` to see the differences.

```
objdump -d -M intel <file name>
```

When building to shared library, GCC has no idea how `partitions` is called. While in C program, GCC know exactly when `partitions` is called (in this case, however, lead to worse performance). This difference in context makes GCC does optimization differently.

You can try different compilers to compare the result. I have checked with GCC 5.4 and Clang 6.0. With GCC 5.4, the Python script runs faster while with Clang, the C program runs faster.

Comment: This remarkably is indeed correct! It turns out calling C from C in this case is faster than C alone due to gcc better optimizations (for some reason) of the standalone function.

See my code here:

https://github.com/octonion/puzzles/tree/master/blackjack/c-c